# Gallery Settings Change available Columns

Tags: admin, filters, shortcode, columns

Is there a filter hook which changes the number of available columns in gallery settings screen. I'm talking about the :

```
<label class="setting">
    <span><?php _e('Columns'); ?></span>
    <select class="columns" name="columns"
        data-setting="columns">
        <?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $i ); ?>" <?php selected( $i, 3 ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $i ); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

in `wp-includes/media-template.php` line `359-369` (*Wordpress v3.5*)

**What I basically want to do is to change `$i <= 9;` to `$i <= 5;` in loop exit condition.**

I guess if I just do so, it will be discarded with the next *Wordpress* update.

Thanks for your help

Eugene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Simple as things sometimes are: No this is not possible. The whole part is hard coded.

### Long answer (not recommended to do so)

You could maybe jump into the `esc_html` and `attribute_escape` filters and just return empty there *), but as those are pretty generic names and would possibly also interfere with other filter results and therefore break other things.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (#82379) Empty Media options */
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpse82379_esc_attr' );
function wpse82379_trigger_filter( $sizes )
{
    if ( 'post' !== get_current_screen()->post )
        return $safe_text;

    add_filter( 'attribute_escape', 'wpse82379_esc_attr', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'esc_html', 'wpse82379_esc_attr', 10, 2 );

    return $sizes;
}
function wpse82379_esc_attr( $safe_text, $text )
{
    if ( ! in_array( absint( $text ), range( 6, 9 ) ) )
        return $safe_text;

    static $counter = 0;
    $static++;

    // 
    if ( 1 === $static )
    {
        ob_start();
        return $safe_text;
    }
    if ( in_array( $static, array( 7, 9 ) ) )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        if ( 'esc_html' === current_filter() )
        {
            $html = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            // In case you want to alter the layout, rework $html and return it
            return '';
        }
    }

    return $safe_text;
}
```

As the escape-filters are present nearly everywhere, it's not really recommended to use them in production (like with the gettext-filters). They trigger on every escape (which are hundreds per page) and can really slow down your system.

### Internals and performance

To work against this, I've used the filter that runs last before the HTML script output to add the callbacks as late as possible. Then I abort as often as possible to not trigger this plugins filters on any other page than the post "add new" screen. After checking the source files HTML, I can see that with version 3.5 we only have two calls for `esc_attr_e()`(which internally triggers `esc_attr` and therefore our filters), but with two strings, so we can safely abort on those. When we finally reach our filters I return an empty string and then instantly remove the filter to not trigger for any later calls.

This is the best you can achieve.

### EDIT

After thinking about it, I used ob caching - not beautiful, but it *should* work (unless I counted wrong). Note: This is coded while writing and thinking, so it's not tested. You'll have to confirm if it works or not.

Final note: You'll have to recheck this plugin after each following version (starting with WP v3.6) to make sure the markup hasn't changed and it's still working as expected.

*) This would leave you with empty strings. In other words: They would still be there but non-functional and empty (no string).

Comment: Final note: You'll have to recheck this plugin after each following version (starting with WP v3.6) to make sure the markup hasn't changed and it's still working as expected.

Comment: Hey Kaiser. Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately the code doesn't work. I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)...` on line `17` in the fist return of `function wpse82379_esc_attr`. The line `return $safe_text;`

Comment: @eugene.kud Yeah, a missing bracket - fixed. Btw: You should try to dig a little bit into error messages, as those are pretty clear and start being help instead of rode blockers when you got around the 5 basic or so messages. Another hint: Use a real IDE as those highlight such errors. I found it with the IDE pretty fast (without counting lines in code in here).

Answer (score 1):

There may or may not be a **filter hook**, but you can restrict the **number of available columns in gallery settings screen** by using styles - specifically the admin CSS.

To achieve choices of 1-5 columns add this to your WordPress admin stylesheet. (You may need to create one.)

## Style

```
.gallery-settings .columns option:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
    }
```

## Function

Tell WordPress to pull this in using [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) in your enqueue PHP file.

```
function wp_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/wordpress-admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_admin_styles');
```

[image]

## Notes

If the `<select>` `<option>` tag(s) isn't there it cannot be chosen.* In the example above all the options starting with the 6th child are targeted. Notice this will be restricted to only the .columns class in a .gallery-settings class, so it's pretty safe to say this probably won't cause any problems with other admin select options.

For my project I targeted only the 9th option with `nth-child(9)`. That's because I'm using [Zurb Foundation's block-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#block-grids) with choices of 1-8 columns. Choosing 9 just breaks the layout.

With this sitting in a stylesheet there's no need to worry about losing anything after an update.

---

*The choice will be limited but keep in mind that the user may still be able to set the column number using the text editor option.
`[gallery columns="9" ids="113,107,92,57,45,44"]` But if you are smart you've probably turned off the text editor option for users anyway.

Comment: Here's what I used to hide everything but 3, 4, 5, 6: `.gallery-settings .columns option:nth-child(-n+2), .gallery-settings .columns option:nth-child(n+7) {display: none;}`